# How to detect threshing in accelerometer?

Tags: algorithm, accelerometer, data-processing

I'm writing an application controlled by an accelerometer built into a wrist watch. I want one of the commands to be "wildly swinging your forehand". How do I detect it and measure for how long it goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To supplement John Fisher's suggestion, I would add:  Look at analyzing this with spectral/Fourier transform techniques.  I would expect to see a strong signal characteristic at low frequencies, but it could easily vary from user to user.

If the characteristic is there, signal processing techniques can help you isolate it and detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Write something to record the measurements while you flail your arm around.  Do it several times in different ways.  Analyze the measurements for a pattern you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Kalman filter to track a moving average of the absolute value of the current acceleration? Or, if you can, the current acceleration minus gravity?

If that goes over a threshold, that indicates a lot of acceleration has been happening recently. That suggests thrashing.